# Java collection : criteria based traversing or another view to a collection

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way or if any java library available which can let me traverse through selected list items only(not all) which satisfies the condition?

For example: I have a list of employee, and I want to traverse the list of employees who are manager only. I don't want to put a condition or filter but want to traverse the list of manager only.

For this, I can define the criteria while creating the list. So every time, when I'll add an item to the list a pointer to a list item, which satisfies the criteria, will be saved in another list.

It's like providing another view to original list.

Although it can be done using filter, but I would have to basically access each list item, compare and then process.

It can have memory overhead as it'll maintain extra list for each criteria, but I believe it'll reduce processing time.

I am expecting that my list would not contain more than 30 items on average.

**Update**

After some brainstorming, I have come up with below solution.

```
View<T>
    List<T>
    boolean checkCondition(T);
    boolean updateView(T);

    managerView
    boolean checkCondition(T){
        return token.getDesignation == designation.MANAGER;
    }

    salaryView
    boolean checkCondition(T){
        :
    }

ViewableList<T> list
    list.addView(managerView)
    list.addView(salaryView)


ViewableList<T>

    List<View<T>> views;


    add(T){
        originalList.add(T);
        foreach views{
         if(view.checkCondition(T)){
            view.add(T);
         }
        }
    }

    addView(View){
        views.add(view)
    }
```

I can achieve Insert, Search, and Delete operation easily. But I am still finding difficulty to update the view when the field of view of an object is updated.

Possible solutions

I annotate list item's field; Write an aspect. So whenever the value of annotated field is changed, it can call updateView() of corresponding view.

```
Employee{
   @View(type=DesignationView.class)
   Designation designation;
}
```

But there is a chance that a field is used in constructing multiple views. So I would have to pass list of view classes in @View annotation, which looks pretty odd. Moreover, I want to avoid use of reflection and aspect due to performance. Otherwise there'll not be any sense to put all this effort.

Please lemme know if you have an idea how I can implement it.

Comment: Too bad you're explicitely excluding a filter, because then, the solution will probably be a homemade collection class. Have you tried to substantiate your believe (that a filter is too slow) with a benchmark? I imagine you won't notice a processing penalty on such a small amount of items.

Comment: If your list would not contain more than 30 items on average, filtering would be a very efficient way of achieving this. If you're using Java 8, you can even write it in a very elegant way.

Comment: If you mean that your original (unfiltered) list is 30 items on average, then just go with easier solution and filter it each time. I assure you, you'll not see any significant difference in performance. [Premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) is evil.

Comment: Maybe [`ObservableList.filtered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#filtered-java.util.function.Predicate-) works for you?

Comment: well!! I was also thinking how much beneficial would it be. when the insertion is 1 time and we need conditional based traversing multiple times. However it'll also increase the maintainability when a criteria is updated, list item should be removed from the view.

Comment: `employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getDesignation() == Designation.MANAGER).forEach(System.out::println);` is 10 times slower that classic for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better if you use Map. In this map, key could be category and value will be list. So when traversing only get the entry for that key.

Comment: well!! this is one of ideas in mind for implementation. But I was looking for some existing API because I need to remove an entry when the value of a field of list item is updated. So may be someone already handling it effectively.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on **I need to remove an entry when the value of a field of list item is updated**, may be I can help you on this !!

Comment: Eg : if I change the designation of an employee from manager to something else my view of manager should be updated. So if the value of a field on which a criteria is defined gets changed, reference from corresponding collection view need to deleted and may need to be another collection view if I have.

Comment: So if i do it in the simplest way 
    `Map < Category C, List < Emp> > map
      Emp emp; Category C1 /*(Earlier)*/, C2/*(New)*/ ;
      map.get ( C1 ).remove (emp)
      emp.setCategory ( c2)
      map.get (c2).add(emp)`                                                                      Here may be you have some reservations    for its complexity. But for your functionality for 30 items at max, it seems perfectly fine.

Comment: Suppose I have a class for list of Emp which maintains views, so above code, updateView(), should be the part of this class. Now if I say Emp.updateDesignation() it should invoke the ListOfEmp.updateView(). I cant see proper implementation of that. If you can, plz share the snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And how do you expect such a thing to be coded in such a way as to be so generic that it's useful as a general purpose library rather than specific to your very narrow requirements?
Which would be the only kind of implementation that it is a sensible idea to release as a standalone library of course.

So no, something like that isn't going to exist. You're going to have to create some of your own code.